# Can't select vertices of different meshes in edit mode

Tags: selection-tools

why can't i select two objects in edit mode?     I am trying to make a face from two different meshes but can't perform the action

Answer (score 1):

**Distinct objects can't share faces**. If you're using blender versions before the (currently Beta) v.2.80 they can't even be edited simultaneously in *Edit Mode*.

If you need to make two meshes a single object, in order to be able to bridge vertices belonging to both of them, then in *Object Mode* select both and ***Join Meshes* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)**. Then Edit the newly created joint object.

Comment: what about A select in edit mode...its not selecting all objects

Comment: When you are in edit mode you have only access to the object that was selected and active in the moment you entered edit mode. Or, in Blender 2.80, to the object**s** that were selected

Comment: so if you hit B (for box select) it will only select one mesh that was currently active when you enter edit mode?

Comment: also wireframe mode is only displaying the selected object and not displaying on the unselected

Comment: yes. Edit mode is for editing the vertices of selected meshes/curves. All the rest is ignored. Object mode deals with the others objects, as the name says. If you need to make faces that use vertices from different objects, just do as the answer says :)